# Ruby autocomplete suggestion on text editors

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, text-editor, atom-editor

In Excel VBA editor, I can enter `"."` after an object that is recognized, and a list pops up. It will help me understand what I am working with, and what can be done with them. Is there such thing in Ruby? or should I ask if such thing exists in text editors? I am using Atom and Sublime.

Comment: Yes, there exist such things for most IDEs and programmers' text editors.

Comment: Rubymine has it, but it's an IDE and there is licensing cost to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) may be useful. It is an autocompletion engine for a number of languages, including Ruby. Make sure you carefully read all of the setup instructions, as well as the options in the settings file. Once it's set up, add the following to your user preferences:

```js
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": "|",
        "selector": "source.ruby"
    },
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source"
    }
],
```

and you'll be able to trigger autocomplete when those keys are pressed.